# CakePHP 2.x Troubles Using minYear/maxYear Params

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I use CakePHP V. 2.3.4 on Windows 7 32 Bits, I'm trying to use `maxYear` and `minYear` parameters, but I don't get the correct values, the code that I use is next:

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'date_birth',
    array(
        'dateFormat'=>'DMY',
        'minYear'=>date('Y')-100,
        'maxYear'=>date('Y')-18
)
```

);

The values shown by cake are: **Min Year: 1913, Max Year: 2013**.
The correct values should be: **Min Year: 1913, Max Year: 1995**.

Also I tried to put:

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'date_birth',
    array(
        'dateFormat'=>'DMY',
        'maxYear'=>date('Y')-18
    )
);
```

But the result is incorrect: **from 1993 to 2013**.

Please help me.

Comment: did you try the latest 2.3.5 version? there have recently some bugfixes in that direction. Maybe the latest master branch doesnt have this issue anymore?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? What does `var_dump(date('Y', strtotime('-100 years')));` output?

Comment: @mark I Update Cake to lastest 2.3.5, the same result.

Comment: @xgalvin PHP is 5.4.14 MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008) X86, Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) PHP/5.4.14.   `var_dump(date('Y', strtotime('-100 years')));` : **string(4) "1913"**

Comment: the test cases are supposed to show that it is working as expected ( https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Test/Case/View/Helper/FormHelperTest.php#L2282 ) . But there could be a flaw or tests missing. Are you able to reproduce the issue in a test?

Comment: Also note that there has recently been changes to auto-expand the range regarding the input year in $this->request->data. Is this an add or edit form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('date_birth', array('type'=>'date',
    'label' => 'Date of birth',
    'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
    'empty' => true,
    'minYear' => date('Y')-100,
    'maxYear' =>date('Y')-18,
    )
    );
?>
```

Note that the solution was to add:  `'empty' => true`

Answer (score 2):

I found that adding a default value to the input corrects this issue; essentially, CakePHP will default the date entry to the current date, and it looks like if you try to set maxYear to something earlier than your default, it ignores maxYear in favor of your default.

So:

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'dob',
    array(
        'type' => 'date',
        'selected' => array(
            'year'=>date('Y')-18
        ),
        'minYear' => date('Y') - 100,
        'maxYear' => date('Y') - 18
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per cakephp document

you can try below code

```
echo $this->Form->input('date_birth', array(
    'label' => 'Date of birth',
    'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
    'minYear' => date('Y') - 70,
    'maxYear' => date('Y') - 18,
));
```

i think it will sure work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just used the current master branch (2.3.5) and uses your exact snippet

```
$result = $this->Form->input('date_of_birth', array(
    'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
    'minYear' => date('Y') - 100,
    'maxYear' => date('Y') - 18));
```

and got:

```
<div class="input text">
    <label for="date_of_birth">Date Of Birth</label>
    <input name="data[date_of_birth]" dateFormat="DMY" minYear="1913" maxYear="1995" type="text" id="date_of_birth"/>
</div>
```

I dont know what you are doing. But it sure looks like it is not cake's fault here..

Note that since 2.3.4 the value range is auto-expected as noted above in the comment if you pass in a year outside of this range as preselect/default value.